# C++ Monitoring Operating System Events and Interrupting them

Tags: c++

Firstly, I know this won't be a trivial task,

How can I watch for specific operating system (Microsoft Windows) events like (file deletion, file change, file create, registry delete, registry change... etc) and ask user for his/her approval.

For example, if some process trying to delete a file, my application should pause that process and display a dialog like "THIS proccess trying to delete THIS file are you allow this?". If user allows it that file should be deleted and that procces should continue it's work.

I know this is not impossible to archieve because I see some firewall+security softwares do this.

I don't know where to start and cant find any document or tutorial about this.

At least can you give me a starting point?

Thanks.

Edit: I want to monitör whole operating system, even if a system proccess tries to change a registry my application should ask for user's permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows allows for *user-mode hooks*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx

If you intend to do more low-level stuff you should study the *WDDM (Windows Driver Model)*, especially *Filter Drivers*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And also [File System Filter Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also [OSRs DMK](http://www.osr.com/dmk.html) might be a turnkey ready solution to use.